# Parameter binding on left joins with array in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I trying to do a left join with where IN clause search. But I couldn't able to bind the array to the query.

```
 $query = DB::table('offers');
        $query->select('id', 'business_id', 'address_id', 'title', 'details', 'value', 'total_available', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'terms', 'type', 'coupon_code', 'is_barcode_available', 'is_exclusive', 'userinformations_id', 'is_used');
        $query->leftJoin('user_offer_collection', function ($join)
        {
            $join->on('user_offer_collection.offers_id', '=', 'offers.id');
            $join->on('user_offer_collection.user_id', 'IN', DB::Raw('?'));
        })->setBindings(array_merge($query->getBindings() , array(array(
            1,2,3
        ))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to bind parameters if you use query builder or eloquent ORM. However, if you use `DB::raw()`, ensure that you binding the parameters.

Try the following:

```
$array = array(1,2,3);

     $query = DB::table('offers');
            $query->select('id', 'business_id', 'address_id', 'title', 'details', 'value', 'total_available', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'terms', 'type', 'coupon_code', 'is_barcode_available', 'is_exclusive', 'userinformations_id', 'is_used');
            $query->leftJoin('user_offer_collection', function ($join) use ($array)
            {
                $join->on('user_offer_collection.offers_id', '=', 'offers.id')
                      ->whereIn('user_offer_collection.user_id', $array);
            });
      $query->get();
```

Comment: Got this ErrorException
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: You query had an issue. I fixed it. pls try now.

Comment: Left Join is not allowing to use whereIn. This is the error I got now Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereIn()